# Why is this minimum cost function returning an insane cost of registration value?

Tags: image-processing, differential-equation

I have a sample program that uses the minimum cost function to align image B to image A.

The method takes two arrays of points and does the summation of all the points in the images for both Matrix A and Matrix B and returns a transformation that should align image B to image A.

My problem is that the matrix entries is returning a transformation that maps image B on top of image A instead of aligning it with image A.

Here is the code that I used in doing this:

```
  public static Transformation ComputeTransformation(List<Point> shp1, List<Point> shp2) {
            PCALib.Matrix A = new PCALib.Matrix(4,4);
            PCALib.Matrix B = new PCALib.Matrix(4, 1);
            //iterate through the points stored in the first shape
            for(int i = 0; i < shp1.Count; i++)
            {
                A[0,0] +=2*shp2[i].X*shp2[i].X+2*shp2[i].Y*shp2[i].Y;
                //completing the remaining entries for matrix A
                //it is important to note that matrix A is 4 by 4
                A[0, 1] += 0;
                A[0, 2] += 2 * shp2[i].X;
                A[0, 3] += 2 * shp2[i].Y;
                A[1, 0] += 0;
                A[1, 1] += 2 * shp2[i].Y * shp2[i].Y+2*shp2[i].X*shp2[i].X;
                A[1, 2] += 2 * shp2[i].Y;
                A[1, 3] += -2 * shp2[i].X;
                A[2, 0] += 2 * shp2[i].X;
                A[2, 1] += 2 * shp2[i].Y;
                A[2, 2] += 2;
                A[2, 3] += 0;
                A[3, 0] += 2 * shp2[i].Y;
                A[3, 1] += -2 * shp2[i].X;
                A[3, 2] += 0;
                A[3, 3] += 2;
                //completing the remaining entries for matrix B
                //the dimensions of Matrix B is 4 by one
                B[0, 0] += 2 * shp1[i].X * shp2[i].X + 2 * shp1[i].Y * shp2[i].Y;
                B[1, 0] += 2 * shp1[i].X * shp2[i].Y - 2 * shp2[i].X * shp1[i].Y;
                B[2, 0] += 2 * shp1[i].X;
                B[3, 0] += 2 * shp1[i].Y;


            }
```

**Transformation class**

```
  public class Transformation
    {
        public double A { get; set; }
        public double B { get; set; }
        public double T1 { get; set; }
        public double T2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Any help to correct the matrix entries for matrix A and matrix B to correct the alignment so that they are on the same level is appreciated.

**Note**

The research paper I used to get the derives for substituting in the loop is from this [site](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317721879_Image_Registration_Based_on_a_Minimized_Cost_Function_and_SURF_Algorithm)

The entries remove the outliers but then places image B on top of image A.

**Output**

Expected output is shown below
[image]

Comment: Code is very tedious to plow through, especially when it is using libraries that aren't called out and it is completely uncommented.  Could you please express what you're trying to do *in math*, or could you *say what algorithm the code should be doing*.  Posting the images you're trying to align would help, too.

Comment: Are you sure that your cost computation isn't either returning the reciprocal or the negative of your real cost?  I assume that when you say the algorithm places the images above one another it means in the sense of physically disjoint, not in the sense of two transparencies that are aligned to match up.

Comment: Posting the images in a few, I really need this to work. The code should be doing the `Minimum Cost Function` for image registration

Comment: And the function uses matrix operations to compute a transformation that should align the two images, completing the matrix entries based on the derives gotten from the equations on the left hand side and the right hand side is the problem. Where can I get an authoritative step step tutorial on how to achieve this?